# Asymptotic sums and liminf

Tags: analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, limsup-and-liminf

Given an arithmetic function $f(n)>0$ with $$\liminf \frac{g(n)}{f(n)}=C$$ for a certain constant $C$ and another function $g(n)>0$, in the study of the asymptotic bound for
$$
\sum_{n\leq x} \frac1{f(n)}\,, \qquad x\rightarrow \infty\,,
$$
can I always say that
$$
\sum_{n\leq x} \frac1{f(n)}\ll \sum_{n\leq x} \frac1{g(n)}
$$
as $x\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: please explain what is this lim and sup

Comment: I downvoted because $\lim \sup f(n) = g(n)$ is not clear. (Why is there an $n$  in the right hand side of this equation?)

Comment: Sorry it was really bad written, meaningless, I edited again the question, hope it's clearer this time.

Comment: @PITTALUGA, if so, why you use sup? What does it mean?

Comment: you're right...I wrote again a wrong statement of the problem, sorry

Comment: It might be true if $C > 0$.

Comment: @Antonio yes I added this hypothesis, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample: $f(n) = n$, $g(n) = (-1)^n n$. Then $C=-1$. $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{f(n)} = \mathcal{O} ( \log x)$, but $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{g(n)} = \mathcal{O} (1)$,

Comment: I see, thanks. But I suppose that if $f(n)>0$ and $g(n)>0$ for every $n$, I can use that estimate, right?

Comment: I am not responding to this question anymore because the question keeps changing, it is a moving target.